# Postgresql JDBC read data with timezone

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark

I am using Postgresql JDBC in order to read data from another server which has different timezone with my client system.

Reading data has some date type columns. I want these columns to become in client system timezone and in order to do that I think there should be a way to say to JDBC that what is the timezone of the server.

I am using JDBC with pypsark.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`timestamptz` data will automatically be converted to the Java default time zone when you retrieve them.

You can change this default with [`java.util.TimeZone.setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault%28java.util.TimeZone%29).

Since that sets the time zone for the whole JVM, which is pretty invasive, I'll show you how to format a timestamp to a certain time zone:

```java
java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();
// fetch the first result column as java.sql.Timestamp object
java.sql.Timestamp d = rs.getObject(1, java.sql.Timestamp.class);
// create a calendar with the appropriate time zone
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(
        java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
// create a DateFormat with the appropriate format and locale
java.text.DateFormat df = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
        java.text.DateFormat.MEDIUM,
        java.text.DateFormat.MEDIUM,
        java.util.Locale.ENGLISH);
// tell the DateFormat to use the calendar with the right time zone
df.setCalendar(cal);
// output will be in the chosen time zone
System.out.println("timestamp = " + df.format(d));
```

Comment: Using `TimeZone.setDefault` might not be a good idea, it can screw up other parts of your application.

Comment: The question asked *these columns to become in client system timezone* and wondered how to set that. But I can add information how to convert data to a certain time zone.